# Android Emulator Segmentation fault (core dumped) On Fedora 33

Tags: android-emulator, fedora

Using the Android 11.0 (R) SDK platform (revision 3), when I run an emulator image (Google Play Intel x86 Atom or Atom_64 System Image, revision 9), the emulator crashes.

Doing the same from the command-line shows that a segmentation fault happens. Here is the verbose output:

```sh
/opt/android/sdk/emulator/emulator -verbose @Pixel_4_API_30 
emulator: Android emulator version 30.2.6.0 (build_id 6962233) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Pixel_4_API_30'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
emulator: argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/

emulator: emuDirName: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator'
emulator: try dir /opt/android/sdk/emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path '/opt/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /opt/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
emulator: Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
emulator: Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
emulator: Setting LD_PRELOAD to /opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libfreetype.so.6
emulator: Running :/opt/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/opt/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-verbose"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "@Pixel_4_API_30"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /opt/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -verbose @Pixel_4_API_30
emulator: autoconfig: -skin pixel_4
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /opt/android/sdk/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//kernel-ranchu
emulator: Target arch = 'x86_64'
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
emulator: VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.0.53
emulator: VERBOSE: FeatureControlImpl.cpp:172: WARNING: unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.

emulator: VERBOSE: FeatureControlImpl.cpp:175: Unexpected feature list:

emulator: VERBOSE: FeatureControlImpl.cpp:177: Vulkan
emulator: VERBOSE: FeatureControlImpl.cpp:179: 

emulator: trying to load skin file '/opt/android/sdk/skins//pixel_4/layout'
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.cmdline' = 'androidboot.logcat=v:* androidboot.consolepipe=qemu_pipe,pipe:logcat'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.logcat' = 'start'
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))


Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: VERBOSE: MultiDisplay.cpp:307: create display 0
emulator: VERBOSE: MultiDisplay.cpp:396: setDisplayPose 0 x 0 y 0 w 1080 h 2280 dpi 0
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.0.53
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86_64
  hw.cpu.ncore = 4
  hw.ramSize = 2048
  hw.screen = multi-touch
  hw.mainKeys = false
  hw.trackBall = false
  hw.keyboard = true
  hw.keyboard.lid = false
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = false
  hw.rotaryInput = false
  hw.gsmModem = true
  hw.gps = true
  hw.battery = true
  hw.accelerometer = true
  hw.gyroscope = true
  hw.audioInput = true
  hw.audioOutput = true
  hw.sdCard = true
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = true
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
  test.delayAdbTillBootComplete = 0
  test.monitorAdb = 0
  hw.lcd.width = 1080
  hw.lcd.height = 2280
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 440
  hw.lcd.backlight = true
  hw.lcd.vsync = 60
  hw.gltransport = pipe
  hw.gltransport.asg.writeBufferSize = 1048576
  hw.gltransport.asg.writeStepSize = 4096
  hw.gltransport.asg.dataRingSize = 32768
  hw.gltransport.drawFlushInterval = 800
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.xOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.yOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.width = 0
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.height = 0
  hw.displayRegion.0.2.xOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.2.yOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.2.width = 0
  hw.displayRegion.0.2.height = 0
  hw.displayRegion.0.3.xOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.3.yOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.3.width = 0
  hw.displayRegion.0.3.height = 0
  hw.display1.width = 0
  hw.display1.height = 0
  hw.display1.density = 0
  hw.display1.xOffset = -1
  hw.display1.yOffset = -1
  hw.display1.flag = 0
  hw.display2.width = 0
  hw.display2.height = 0
  hw.display2.density = 0
  hw.display2.xOffset = -1
  hw.display2.yOffset = -1
  hw.display2.flag = 0
  hw.display3.width = 0
  hw.display3.height = 0
  hw.display3.density = 0
  hw.display3.xOffset = -1
  hw.display3.yOffset = -1
  hw.display3.flag = 0
  hw.gpu.enabled = true
  hw.gpu.mode = host
  hw.initialOrientation = Portrait
  hw.camera.back = virtualscene
  hw.camera.front = emulated
  vm.heapSize = 512
  hw.sensors.light = true
  hw.sensors.pressure = true
  hw.sensors.humidity = true
  hw.sensors.proximity = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.orientation = true
  hw.sensors.temperature = true
  hw.sensor.hinge = true
  hw.sensor.hinge.count = 0
  hw.sensor.hinge.type = 0
  hw.sensor.hinge.sub_type = 0
  hw.sensor.hinge.fold_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture = 1
  hw.sensor.roll = false
  hw.sensor.roll.count = 0
  hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture = 6
  hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.2_at_posture = 6
  hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.3_at_posture = 6
  hw.useext4 = true
  hw.arc = false
  hw.arc.autologin = false
  kernel.path = /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//kernel-ranchu
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 2701m
  disk.vendorPartition.initPath = /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//vendor.img
  disk.vendorPartition.size = 800m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 6g
  disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path = /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/encryptionkey.img
  PlayStore.enabled = true
  avd.name = Pixel_4_API_30
  avd.id = Pixel_4_API_30
  fastboot.forceColdBoot = false
  android.sdk.root = /opt/android/sdk
  android.avd.home = /home/lpellegr/.android/avd
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/opt/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "127.0.0.53"
emulator: argv[03] = "-mem-path"
emulator: argv[04] = "/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img"
emulator: argv[05] = "-mem-file-shared"
emulator: argv[06] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[07] = "null"
emulator: argv[08] = "-device"
emulator: argv[09] = "goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin"
emulator: argv[10] = "-cpu"
emulator: argv[11] = "android64"
emulator: argv[12] = "-enable-kvm"
emulator: argv[13] = "-smp"
emulator: argv[14] = "cores=4"
emulator: argv[15] = "-m"
emulator: argv[16] = "2048"
emulator: argv[17] = "-lcd-density"
emulator: argv[18] = "440"
emulator: argv[19] = "-object"
emulator: argv[20] = "iothread,id=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[21] = "-nodefaults"
emulator: argv[22] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[23] = "/opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//kernel-ranchu"
emulator: argv[24] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[25] = "/opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[26] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[27] = "if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=/opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//system.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[28] = "-device"
emulator: argv[29] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[30] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[31] = "if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[32] = "-device"
emulator: argv[33] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[34] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[35] = "if=none,index=2,id=userdata,if=none,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[36] = "-device"
emulator: argv[37] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[38] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[39] = "if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,if=none,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[40] = "-device"
emulator: argv[41] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[42] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[43] = "if=none,index=4,id=vendor,if=none,file=/opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//vendor.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[44] = "-device"
emulator: argv[45] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[46] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[47] = "if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,if=none,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[48] = "-device"
emulator: argv[49] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[50] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[51] = "user,id=mynet"
emulator: argv[52] = "-device"
emulator: argv[53] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet"
emulator: argv[54] = "-device"
emulator: argv[55] = "virtio-rng-pci"
emulator: argv[56] = "-show-cursor"
emulator: argv[57] = "-device"
emulator: argv[58] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_1"
emulator: argv[59] = "-device"
emulator: argv[60] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_2"
emulator: argv[61] = "-device"
emulator: argv[62] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_3"
emulator: argv[63] = "-device"
emulator: argv[64] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_4"
emulator: argv[65] = "-device"
emulator: argv[66] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_5"
emulator: argv[67] = "-device"
emulator: argv[68] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_6"
emulator: argv[69] = "-device"
emulator: argv[70] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_7"
emulator: argv[71] = "-device"
emulator: argv[72] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_8"
emulator: argv[73] = "-device"
emulator: argv[74] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_9"
emulator: argv[75] = "-device"
emulator: argv[76] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_10"
emulator: argv[77] = "-device"
emulator: argv[78] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_11"
emulator: argv[79] = "-device"
emulator: argv[80] = "virtio-keyboard-pci"
emulator: argv[81] = "-L"
emulator: argv[82] = "/opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios"
emulator: argv[83] = "-soundhw"
emulator: argv[84] = "hda"
emulator: argv[85] = "-vga"
emulator: argv[86] = "none"
emulator: argv[87] = "-append"
emulator: argv[88] = "qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR30X2X6X0 clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.vsync=60 qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=294M@0-4G qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 loop.max_part=7 androidboot.vbmeta.size=6144 androidboot.vbmeta.hash_alg=sha256 androidboot.vbmeta.digest=41a8a81d9ef6e2e9044050c3852061de69f69c4d73bf3ca684173ed597d3a040 androidboot.boot_devices=pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0 qemu.hwcodec.avcdec=2 qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec=2 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m qemu.camera_protocol_ver=1"
emulator: argv[89] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[90] = "/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /opt/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -dns-server 127.0.0.53 -mem-path /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img -mem-file-shared -serial null -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin -cpu android64 -enable-kvm -smp cores=4 -m 2048 -lcd-density 440 -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -nodefaults -kernel /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//kernel-ranchu -initrd /opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//ramdisk.img -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=/opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//system.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,if=none,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,if=none,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=4,id=vendor,if=none,file=/opt/android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64//vendor.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,if=none,file=/home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -device virtio-rng-pci -show-cursor -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_1 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_2 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_3 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_4 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_5 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_6 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_7 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_8 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_9 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_10 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_11 -device virtio-keyboard-pci -L /opt/android/sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR30X2X6X0 clocksource=pit android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.vsync=60 qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=294M@0-4G qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 loop.max_part=7 androidboot.vbmeta.size=6144 androidboot.vbmeta.hash_alg=sha256 androidboot.vbmeta.digest=41a8a81d9ef6e2e9044050c3852061de69f69c4d73bf3ca684173ed597d3a040 androidboot.boot_devices=pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0 qemu.hwcodec.avcdec=2 qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec=2 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m qemu.camera_protocol_ver=1' -android-hw /home/lpellegr/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Android qemu version 30.2.6.0 (build_id 6962233) (CL:N/A)

emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'front'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '440'
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: false
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: Adding boot property: 'net.wifi_mac_prefix' = '5554'
Not using any http proxy
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'Europe/Paris'
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: VERBOSE: GrpcServices.cpp:286: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
emulator: emulator_window_fb_rotate

emulator: VERBOSE: MultiDisplay.cpp:677: config multidisplay with config.ini 0x0 0x0 0x0
emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default

emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default

emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:385: Found: 3 adb executables
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:387: Adb: /opt/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:387: Adb: /opt/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:387: Adb: /opt/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:408: Path:/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 41
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:408: Path:/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 41
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:408: Path:/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 41
emulator: _hwFingerprint_connect: connect finger print listen is called

emulator: got message from guest system fingerprint HAL

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is a *strace*:

https://gist.github.com/lpellegr/a3cb7fcc86ede7f320b3a65875023293

I am running Fedora 33, with kernel *5.9.11-200.fc33.x86_64*. Using option `-gpu guest` when launching the emulator does not help.

It looks like I have no permissions to submit a bug report to the Emulator category of the Android bug tracker.

What's wrong? how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Setting this line in the AVD config (should be `~/.android/avd/{emulator name}.ini`) fixed this for me:

```
hw.gpu.enabled = no
```

I don't recall what I set the `hw.gpu.mode` line as but I think it may have been `auto`.

That at least got it running for me, but it was really slow.

Not sure what the rest of your setup looks like, but in my case I have an NVIDIA GPU and had to install the proprietary drivers to get it to use host GPU properly. [This guide helped me out](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/#nvidia-install). The difference is night and day. Oh, I also needed to install [KVM](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-kvm-on-fedora/).

Comment: For me the correct file to edit on Fedora 33 was ~/.android/avd/{emulator name}.ini

Comment: I double checked my own stuff and you're right, it was the same for me. Thank you! (edited my comment)

Comment: I have the same issue, but SW rendering isn't working for me; the emulator's System UI keeps crashing every couple of seconds.